# Redirect to mobile pages with different filename extension using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have created a desktop website at www.domain.com and a mobile site at m.domain.com., and am redirecting smartphone visitors to the latter using .htaccess:

```
# Mobile redirect #
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# prevent looping
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.goldenhinde.com$

# if the browser accepts these mime-types, it's definitely mobile, or pretending to be
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]

# a bunch of user agent tests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*).goldenhinde.com/.*$ [NC]

# rewrite rules here
RewriteRule .? http://m.goldenhinde.com%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=302]
```

However, the problem I have is that URLs for pages on my desktop site do not feature a filename extension (*e.g.* www.website.com/contact), whereas those on the mobile site have the .php suffix (*e.g.* m.website.com/contact.**php**).

When visitors enter an address such as www.website.com/contact on their smartphones, I would like them to be redirected to m.website.com/contact.php, but this is obviously not occurring at present due to the inclusion of the filename extension in the mobile version.

Can you advise what code I can add to my .htaccess file so the desktop pages automatically redirect to their mobile equivalent.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to the end

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m.goldenhinde.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,R=301]
```